# grab_set in tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

I've seen many examples of grab_set() being used for modal windows for tkinter but I can't get it to work for my application.
I am creating a second window as my 'Settings' window which is called from the Menu of the main application.

example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Main(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args, *kwargs)

        button = tk.Button(self,text="second window", command=lambda:Settings())
        button.pack()


class Settings(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args, *kwargs)
        button = tk.Button(self,text="quit", command=lambda: quit())
        button.pack()
        self.grab_set()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Main()
    app.mainloop()
```

Right now I can still click the 'Settings' button to create as many instances of `Settings` as the pc would allow. How do I restrict clickability to the main application window until the second one is closed first?

Comment: You say you have the second window in a second process, but I see nothing in your code that indicates you're running a separate process.

Comment: at least from what I understand. When opening separate application windows in tkinter, they use separate processes (as in they each have their own taskbar icon), I could be wrong though. I read in a post that if they application windows do not share the same process then the grab_set will not work. I could be in over my head too though

Comment: edit to previous post... I believe the separate process only affects the `wait_window`. Basically I have two separate files of the same thing with modified content. Both of which I used @BryanOakley example for. hope this makes a bit more sense.

Comment: If you are not actually using separate processes, you can't create more than one instance of `Tk` at a time. If you need extra windows you need to create instances of `Toplevel`. When you have two instances of `Tk` things simply won't work the way you expect them to.

Comment: _"When opening separate application windows in tkinter, they use separate processes"_ - that is a false statement. Unless you explicitly create another process or thread, a tkinter application is a single thread in a single process.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech . I apologize for not having a working test code. My code is getting quite extensive and to be honest, I don't know how much I need to post to make is usable without extra clutter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a super simple example of how you can open another window using `Toplevel` and how you can edit stuff on the main window from the Toplevel window.

Its very basic but it should be a good enough example to illustrate what is required in tkinter to open new window.

UPDATE: Added the `grab_set()` method as pointed out by Bryan in the comments.

The `grab_set()` method according to the [documentation](https://dafarry.github.io/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.grab_set-method) routes all events for this application to this widget.

Note: This would be along the lines of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is the smallest possible bit of code to get the point across while also being testable.

```
from tkinter import *


class GUI(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        
        self.master = master
        self.my_frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.my_frame.pack()

        self.button1 = Button(self.master, text="Open New Window", command = self.open_toplevel_window)
        self.button1.pack()
        
        self.text = Text(self.master, width = 20, height = 3)
        self.text.pack()
        self.text.insert(END, "Before\ntop window\ninteraction")
        
    def open_toplevel_window(self):
        self.top = Toplevel(self.master)
        #this forces all focus on the top level until Toplevel is closed
        self.top.grab_set() 
        
        def replace_text():
            self.text.delete(1.0, END)
            self.text.insert(END, "Text From\nToplevel")
        
        top_button = Button(self.top, text = "Replace text in main window",
                            command = replace_text)
        top_button.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    app = GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Here is an example when using a separate class for the Toplevel:

```
from tkinter import *


class GUI(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        
        self.master = master
        self.my_frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.my_frame.pack()

        self.button1 = Button(self.master, text="Open New Window",
                              command = open_toplevel_window)
        self.button1.pack()
        
        self.text = Text(self.master, width = 20, height = 3)
        self.text.pack()
        self.text.insert(END, "Before\ntop window\ninteraction")
        
class open_toplevel_window(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.grab_set()
        
        def replace_text():
            app.text.delete(1.0, END)
            app.text.insert(END, "Text From\nToplevel")
        
        top_button = Button(self, text = "Replace text in main window",
                            command = replace_text)
        top_button.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    app = GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: since the original question is about doing a grab, this example would be better if you included a grab on the new toplevel.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Added the `grab_set()` method with notes. Thanks for bring that to my attention.

Comment: Thanks for the example guys. I posted my fix but need to give SierraMountainTech and @BryanOakley credit for ultimately giving me the answer to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my problem

```
import tkinter as tk

class Main(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args, *kwargs)

        self.button = tk.Button(self,text="second window", command=lambda: SecondWindow())
        self.button.pack()


class SecondWindow(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self,*args, *kwargs)
        self.button = tk.Button(self,text="quit", command=lambda: quit())
        self.button.pack()
        self.grab_set()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Main()
    app.mainloop()
```

as per Sierra Mountain Tech and Bryan Oakley's suggestion. I have changed my `Settings` class to `Toplevel` and it does exactly what I want.
My acutal application has the two in different modules but yield the same results.

Comment: I am glad you figured it out. I was just updating my answer to include a 2nd class for top level :)

Comment: This is a good illustration of why it's important to create a [mcve]. Reducing the problem down to the smallest example possible makes it much easier to see what the problem is.

Comment: I definitely need to practice using Minimal Complete and Verifiable examples. I appreciate you guiding me in the right direction through.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following line after the line containing the grab_set method:

```
self.wait_window(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow focus with takefocus = True and you give the focus to it with focus_set()

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    Toplevel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.takefocus = True
    self.focus_set()
```