# How to bring dialogue box window to appear at the front in Tkinter module of Python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, window

I am using Python 2.7 Tkinter module to create a GUI. In this GUI there are two windows:

1. Dialogue box which asks user to enter something.
2. Main user interface that loads up after user enters value.

The problem that I am facing is that the 2nd window appears before the 1st window such that the 2nd window covers up the whole 1st window so I literally have to drag out the 2nd window to enter the value in the 1st window such that the 2nd window loads up. How do I make sure that the 1st window i.e the Dialogue box always appear at the front.

This is the code of the Dialogue box window.

```
top = TK()
value += tkSimpleDialog.askstring("Fruit", "Enter fruit number: e.g 3", parent=top)
```

Comment: I like this question, but do you really need the mechanism of it? Why dont you build a TopLevel instead? I would have less to explain. :D you could also take a look on this https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm

Comment: Here are some simple exampels without the mechanism: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45172395/13629335 https://stackoverflow.com/a/29498445/13629335

Comment: Try adding `top.update()` before `askstring(...)`.  Note that `top = TK()` should be `top = Tk()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `top.lift()` this will get your window to the front.